# Custom actions on setup installer not working in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I have this project which requires to run a InstallerClass as part of the installation.

I added it as a Custom Action, and it has been working like that for ages. We did some maintenance to this class, cleaned the solution, rebuild the solution, and now the Custom  Actions are not being triggered.

I know they are not being triggered, because I had `Debugger.Break()` calls working prior to the cleaning, and the fact the registry entries that are meant to be created are not created anymore.

What is going on? What can I do to obtain more info from the MSI installer?

For what is worth, my machine is 64 bit, but the project is mean for and built as 32 bit (*x86*). I used to build it as *Any CPU* before, now it doesn't matter what I built it with, no results.

I've been done some more research and found that if `Debugger.Break();` is no longer working could be due to a dependency issue, I got no error or warnings on the project though. I ran the MSI on verbose, but I can't make a thing out of it either.

After getting lost on the logs I got nothing useful. I started over again and created a new Installer class with a pop window. that worked. Added a Break() afterwards, it worked too, added the using Process statement I wanted to run and it worked... once.

After that I found that: If I leave the `Debugger.Break()` it gets skipped, but if I remove it it works...

Yes, this is THAT random... What's the deal?

Comment: How are you creating the MSI? You can get verbose logs from the MSI e.g msiexec /i mymsi.exe /L*V log.txt.

Comment: already managed to get a verbose output, doesn't mention any action being skipped, can't make anything out that looks like an error

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth first checking in source control what changes were made to the installer.

In any case, I have seen various weird cases where the installers acted weird. A few suggestions:

- Ensure base.Install is last.
- Run VS as Administrator.
- Recreate the installer project (they can get corrupted).

Answer (score 0):

Try the [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) on another machine - if it works then nothing wrong with MSI and problem is with your machine. It is possible one MSI execution may have left some remnants.

Uninstall the product from your machine and then try [MSIZap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the product code. This will cleanup your machine for any remnants that uninstall may have left behind.